# Go HTML page repeats the content inside it on each reload

Tags: html, go, templates, go-templates

I'm in the process of creating a go package that's a mix of django, express and gin and I'm already having many difficulties but it's one that's been so annoying for the past couple days.
When reloading an html page that's served via the Ctx.HTML() or Ctx.Template() funcs it repeats it's content. With a result like this:
[The problem GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktHMT.gif)

I'll leave the link to the issue here -> [/dpouris/goster/issues/5](https://github.com/dpouris/goster/issues/5)

I've tried pretty much every type of test and manual printing of errors and whatnot but have yet to find a solution :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you! :)

Comment: This needs some code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The project shares request-specific state across multiple requests. Rendering the same HTML file multiple times is just one of many other problems caused by same design flaw. Without a [mcve] *within the question* (not a link to a separate website), the question fails SO's [ask].